# null check and string concatenation

Tags: oracle, null

Can I do better than this query?

```
 select func_returns_str('key1') || 
        nvl2( func_returns_str('key2'), 
              ',' || func_returns_str('key2'), 
              null) 
   from dual;
```

I would like to avoid calling `func_returns_str('key2')` twice. 
`func_returns_str` returns a varchar.

Elaborating further:
 `func_returns_str` could be a generic function like `substr()` in Oracle which you can't change the definition.

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the table? What kind of results you are looking for? What does func_returns_str do besides return a varchar (lookup, etc)?

Comment: With a built in functions, Oracle may know which ones are idempotent and just re-use the return value instead of calling twice, without you needing to change your code. SQL is declarative, not imperative. Not leaving as an answer because I'm unsure how to prove either way.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper for the `nvl2` call:

```
create or replace function add_comma(s varchar) return varchar as
begin
  return case when s is null then null else ','||s end;
end;
/

with t as (select 'key2' as val from dual union all select null from dual)
select val, nvl2( substr(val, 3, 2), ','||substr(val, 3, 2), null) as orig, 
       add_comma(substr(val, 3, 2)) as wrapped
from t;

VAL  ORIG WRAPPED
---- ---- -------
key2 ,y2  ,y2
```

alternatively you can use a `with` clause (also know as a [CTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) ):

```
with t as (select substr('key2', 3, 2) as s from dual)
select nvl2(s, ','||s, null) from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function to wrap func_returns_str in that could be used for the later calls and appends the comma itself if the return value is not null.